# rxvt-unicode some colors missing on CentOS 7

Tags: terminal, colors, rxvt

I have [the following configuration](https://github.com/ChoppinBlockParty/Yuki-s-.files). It works fine on Ubuntu 16. However, on CentOS 7, **some** colors of rxvt are not displayed (just white), and some are totally fine, there is no obvious differences which colors are missing, which are not. urxvt version is the same. Configurations of zsh, tmux, urxvt are the same from the repo above. I am using `URxvt*termName: screen-256color` Is there some other config for rxvt? Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

> I am using URxvt*termName: screen-256color

That's not a wise idea. The TERM variable is supposed to describe the terminal's behavior, otherwise faulty behavior (e.g. the one you're experiencing) is bound to happen. Urxvt is not screen, they are not fully compatible. Stick to what it sets by default (e.g. rxvt-unicode-256color), use screen-256color inside screen or tmux only.